# El Capitan Downloads folder in dock doesn't expand

Tags: macos, dock

When I click on my downloads folder in dock it opens the downloads folder in Finder, instead of showing the expanded file contents. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is, remove it from the Dock and add it back.

- Control-click the Downloads Dock Tile, select Options > Remove from Dock
- Then in Finder, select your Downloads folder and control-click > Add to Dock